# How to get Notification/Reminder for Facebook Friends Upcoming Birthdays

Tags: android, facebook, facebook-graph-api, android-facebook

I am writing an App in which i am *Fetching List of all my Facebook Friends*..

But now i want to add one more functionality in my app **to get Notification/Reminder for upcoming friends birthdays**

I am using below code to get List of all friends:

```
 public class FriendListAdapter extends BaseAdapter implements
        SectionIndexer {
    private LayoutInflater mInflater;

    private GetProfilePictures picturesGatherer = null;
    FriendsList friendsList;
    private String[] sections;

    Hashtable<Integer, FriendItem> listofshit = null;

    public FriendListAdapter(FriendsList friendsList) {

        this.friendsList = friendsList;
        sections = new String[getCount()];
        listofshit = new Hashtable<Integer, FriendItem>();


        for (int i = 0; i < getCount(); i++) {
            try {

                sections[i] = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i).getString("name")
                        .substring(0);
                sections[i] = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i)
                        .getString("birthday").substring(1);


            } catch (JSONException e) {
                sections[i] = "";

            }
        }
        if (picturesGatherer == null) {
            picturesGatherer = new GetProfilePictures();
        }
        picturesGatherer.setAdapterForListener(this);
        mInflater = LayoutInflater.from(friendsList.getBaseContext());
    }

    public int getCount() {

        if (jsonArray == null)
            return 0;
        return jsonArray.length();
    }

    public Object getItem(int position) {

        return listofshit.get(position);
    }

    public long getItemId(int position) {

        return position;
    }

    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {


        JSONObject jsonObject = null;
        try {
            jsonObject = jsonArray.getJSONObject(position);
        } catch (JSONException e) {

        }

        FriendItem friendItem;

        if (convertView == null) {
            convertView = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.single_friend, null);
            friendItem = new FriendItem();

            convertView.setTag(friendItem);
        } else {
            friendItem = (FriendItem) convertView.getTag();
        }

        friendItem.friendPicture = (ImageView) convertView
                .findViewById(R.id.picture_square);
        friendItem.friendName = (TextView) convertView
                .findViewById(R.id.name);
        friendItem.friendDob = (TextView) convertView
                .findViewById(R.id.dob);
        friendItem.friendLayout = (RelativeLayout) convertView
                .findViewById(R.id.friend_item);

        try {
            String uid = jsonObject.getString("uid");
            String url = jsonObject.getString("pic_square");
            friendItem.friendPicture.setImageBitmap(picturesGatherer
                    .getPicture(uid, url));
        } catch (JSONException e) {

            friendItem.friendName.setText("");
            friendItem.friendDob.setText("");
        }

        try {
            friendItem.friendName.setText(jsonObject.getString("name"));
            friendItem.friendDob.setText(jsonObject.getString("birthday"));
        } catch (JSONException e) {

            friendItem.friendName.setText("");
            friendItem.friendDob.setText("");
        }

        listofshit.put(position, friendItem);
        return convertView;
    }

    public int getPositionForSection(int position) {
        return position;
    }

    public int getSectionForPosition(int position) {
        return position;
    }

    public Object[] getSections() {
        return sections;
    }
}
```

Comment: You want this on an action inside app, or as an offline functionality?

Comment: @Sahil i want user will get reminder even he/she is not using app...

Answer (score 0):

You may use CRON and the [Notification API](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/howtos/notifications-api/) of facebook.

1. First you need to store the **id** and the **extended access token**  of the **user** in your database.
2. Then, run your scheduler and fetch the friends' birthday of each user using the user's token
3. Send the notification to the user using notification API (just requires the **APP access token**- which you can obtain from [here](https://developers.facebook.com/tools/access_token/))